# Keras layer to change sign of input tensor only to specific elements

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to write a Keras layer (with TF backend) to invert the sign of the elements 1, 5 and 9 of the input tensor. 
[for your curiosity: the net deals with four-momenta in the (pT,eta,phi,M) representation. I want to flip the sign of the pseudorapidity component].

Naively, I'd do something like this:

```
def flip_eta( x ):
   # you can't do this with tensors
   x[1] = -x[1]
   x[5] = -x[5]
   x[9] = -x[9]

   return x
```

However, it does not work, and I get the following error:

```
    x[1] = -x[1]
TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment
```

I'm not really familiar with TF operations. Is there a simple way to apply a transformation like this?

Cheers,
Riccardo

Comment: Have a look at [tf.scatter_update](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_update).

Comment: I suppose I may solve the problem with a matrix operation, by multiplying the input vector e.g. by diag(1,-1,1,1...)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

`x[1] = tf.math.negative(x[1])`

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/negative

Comment: I still get: x[1] = tf.math.negative(x[1])
TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment

Answer (score 0):

Import the backend (TensorFlow)

```
from keras import backend as K
```

Define your input array

```
val = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

Transform it into a variable

```
kvar = K.variable(value=val, dtype='float64', name='example_var')
```

Define the mask you want and also transform it into a variable:

```
mask = np.ones([len(val)])
mask[[1,5,9]] = -1
mask = K.variable(value=mask, dtype='float64', name='mask')
```

Multiply the mask by your original vector

```
result = val * mask
```

Evaluate the result

```
K.eval(result)

> array([ 0., -1.,  2.,  3.,  4., -5.,  6.,  7.,  8., -9., 10.])
```

Comment: If I do this:

```
def flip_eta( x ):
 
   mask = np.ones(13)
   mask[[1,5,9]] = -1
   mask = K.variable(value=mask, dtype='float64', name='mask')

   y = x * mask
   
   return y
```

And use the function like this in Keras:

```
D_flipped = Lambda( filp_eta )(D)
```

I still get an error:

ValueError: Incompatible type conversion requested to type 'float32' for variable of type 'float64_ref'